# How to implement database driven if-else statements?

Tags: database, django, if-statement, django-models, conditional-statements

My programming task right now is to implement if-elif-else constructs in a database, so that users can easily compose their conditional statements.

In the conditional block the user selects conditional operators, function calls, setting parameters and checking against the return value - composing a sequence of condition tests.

In the execution block the user should be able to select function calls and set parameters - composing a sequence of function calls.

I could use a text field, write a parser and use eval(), but this is not an option:

1. Security
2. To much hassle (or do you know a good package?)
3. User should need no programming knowledge.

To be clear: The task again and a sample conditional statement I would like to map to the database:

Problem: Create an "if-elsif-else construct" that is database driven and easily clickable and performs well.

1. Conditional Statement mapped into the database. I'd like to stay in the Django ORM
2. Maximize Performance: The database should not be littered with objects, so that performance is reasonable good. If I have 100k of different conditional statements I do not want to have more than 10 objects each on average. The less the better.
3. Maximize Possible Complexity: type and number of conditional statements should resemble the possible complexity of written conditional statements.
4. Minimize Difficulty: The usage of the construct should be easy to grasp. The conditional statement should be easily composeable. User needs no programming knowledge but has basic (human) logical understanding.

```
if something(p1, p2, px, ret) and someotherthing(p1, p2, px, ret):
    dothis(p1, p2, px)
    thendothat(p1, p2, px)
elif somethought(p1, p2, px, ret) or someotherthougt(p1, p2, px, ret) and acrazythought(p1, p2, px, ret):
    thinkthis(p1, p2, px)
    thenthinkthat(p1, p2, px)
    finallyconclude(p1, p2, px)
else:
    sayinaudiblethings(p1, p2, px)
    donothing(p1, p2, px)
```

SubTasks:

1. Database Model (Django ORM)
2. Generic View, Template and Form handling

If you have no problem at all - and a good solution - please share it!

I am currently working on a solution and eventually would post it.

Comment: One note regarding the minmax task description. I am well aware that these boundaries are relative and might influence each other.

Comment: I am not sure what is the question you are trying to ask. Please rephrase your question to a specific problem (see the [guidelines](http://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask)); otherwise I fear your question will be closed. The short answer to your question seems to be [`Q` object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/queries/#complex-lookups-with-q-objects).

Comment: What exactly did you not understand? I am asking how to implement an if-elif-else construct into the database, that meets certain criteria. Could you state how you would achieve this with just Q-Objects